# Compiler flags when setting debug and release mode

Tags: c, build

gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
    cmake version 2.8.10.2
    c89

I am using cmake as my build system. And I want to set the flags accordingly to either debug or release.

Compile with debug

```
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -g -m32 -D_DEBUG -O0 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REETRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE")
```

Compile with release

```
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "-Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -m32 -DNDEBUG -O2 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_REETRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE")
```

For the debug I have included the flags `-g` and set optimization to level 0.

For the release I have removed flags `-g` and add the `N` for `-DNDEBUG`, `-DNREETRANT`, and `-DNTHREAD_SAFE` and set the optimization to level 2.

I am right in saying that the `N` means `NO DEBUG`?

Is this all I would need to do to distinguish between a debug and release build?

Comment: The defines `DEBUG` and `NDEBUG` are common for debug and release compilations, respectively. However, don't you want the release build to be reentrant and thread safe as well? Then don't change those defines.

Comment: Why would you set -DNREENTRANT and -DNTHREAD_SAFE in release mode? Don't you run your code in multi-thread environment in release mode?

Comment: `NDEBUG` is a preprocessor symbol that controls if `assert` is active or not, as specified by the C standard. `_DEBUG` doesn't have the same status.

Comment: @Jay, I have edited my source code for those changes. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What would you need `-D_DEBUG` for if you could just as well check for the *absence* of `NDEBUG`? (Unless, of course, you want seperate control over `assert` and other debugging `#ifdef`'s. I never had that need.)
- Why would you want different settings for reentrancy and thread safety?

Bottom line, what you want different between Debug and Release code is completely up to you. I want my debug code to include coverage information, and my release code to be `-O3`. Your mileage obviously varies. Neither way is "right" or "wrong".

You might also want to note that:

- CMake sets stuff like `-g -O0` and `-O2` automatically, so it would be sufficient to append the desired warnings and additional flags.
- You might want to keep an eye on portability and check for `if ( CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC )` (or `..._GNUCC` for C++) before you set the compiler flags.
- As Ling Kun said, you can keep `-g` even in Release code. At least during development it is useful, and you can command CMake to `strip` executables during installation. (Personally, I strive for not having to make my customers extract post-mortem stack / core dumps. ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

Here is some recommendations based on your CMake flags:

1. Debug mode `-g -O0`, and release mode `-O2 -g` . It is better to add the `-g` flag even for O2 release mode if the code size is not critical. With `-g`,  some symbol information of the code is included, it only increase the whole binary size by about 10%~ 20%, but users can help give you a stack dump, which can help a lot for debug.
2. Use `-UDEBUG -UREETRANT` instead of `-DNDEBUG -DNREETRANT`. The `-DMACRO` flag is just like add `#define MACOR` in your code, and if you have code region like `#ifdef MACRO SOME_DEBUG_CODE #endif`, the preprocessor will keep the code there, while `-UDEBUG` flag is like `#undefine MACRO`, and the preprocessor will delete the `SOME_DEBUG_CODE`.  If you just add `-DNDEBUG -DNREETRANT`, it is like add`#define NDEBUG #defin NREETRANT` in your code, which is meaningless.

Comment: Re -g: leave it on for your release builds but use `strip` on your binary before shipping it to save size (and gain a little obscurity). You can still interpret a stack trace or core dump using the unstripped binary (which you store).

Comment: `-UDEBUG` is not equivalent to `-DNDEBUG` in the context for assert, as the assert statements are only removed using `-DNDEBUG`.